# U.S. Map plugin, new buttons with the state data / hover ability

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQuery U.S. map plugin.

Found here. https://github.com/NewSignature/us-map/

I am trying to add 10 additional buttons, that will ALSO correlate with the state data. For instance by default you can HOVER over a state and there is a HOVER COLOR. I'm trying to maintain this effect over the new states in which I'm creating ADDITIONAL buttons for.

For instance, new button below.

```
$("#star_btn1").click(function() {
$('#ca').toggle();
```

**The plugin has hover styles defined and customizeable.**

```
'stateHoverStyles': {
    fill: '#ffc600',
},
```

and:

```
   _defaultMouseOverAction: function(stateData) {
      // hover effect
      this.bringShapeToFront(stateData.shape);
      this.paper.safari();

      // ... for the state
      var attrs = {};
      if(this.options.stateSpecificHoverStyles[stateData.name]) {
        $.extend(attrs, this.options.stateHoverStyles, this.options.stateSpecificHoverStyles[stateData.name]);
      } else {
        attrs = this.options.stateHoverStyles;
      }

      stateData.shape.animate(attrs, this.options.stateHoverAnimation);
```

**Any ideas how I can incorporate this with my new buttons as well?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the event handlers for the buttons trigger the events for the map plugin.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="stateBtn" data-name="CA">California</button>
<button type="button" class="stateBtn" data-name="MN">Minnesota</button>
<br />
<br />
<div id="map" style="width: 550px; height: 350px;"></div>
<div id="clicked-state"></div>
```

Original JavaScript for the map:

```
$('#map').usmap({
    click: function (event, data) {
        $('#clicked-state')
            .text('You clicked: ' + data.name)
            .parent().effect('highlight', {
            color: '#C7F464'
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Additional JavaScript for the buttons:

```
$('.stateBtn').on('click mouseout mouseover', function(e) {
    var name = $(this).attr('data-name');
    $('#map').usmap('trigger', name, e.type, e);
});
```

Notice how additional state buttons can be added without needing to add any additional JavaScript code.

[**Demo on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fypnjo8f/1/)

[US Map Plugin Documentation](http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/)

Comment: Well said, sir. Well.. Said.